# Text disppears from text field after clicking submit button html php. Need the text to stay

Tags: php, html, button, submit, textfield

I have a submit button in my form which when clicked, the text in my text field disappears. I basically need the text to stay because I have another button that requires the text in that text field. The two buttons are parts of two different functions and I was wondering if there was a way to use the value of the variable in the function of one button in the function of the other.

For example, here is the code for one of the buttons:

```
Enter customer name<input type="text" name="cname">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Display">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sub'])){
    display();
}
function display(){
    include 'config.php';
    $searchstr=$_GET['cname'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='cname1' value=".$searchstr.">";
    $td=$_GET['cname1'];
    $sql="select * from info where cname='$searchstr';";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($searchstr==""){
    $message="Please enter a customer name";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); 
    window.location.href='retreive.php';</script>";
}
else{
    echo "<table id='info' border='1px solid black'><tr padding='2'><th>Customer Name</th><th>Purchase Order Date</th><th>Started?</th><th>Reason (If any)</th><th>Tentative start date</th><th>Progress</th><th>Current Status</th><th></tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cname=$row['cname'];
        $podate=$row['podate'];
        $started=$row['started'];
        $reason=$row['reason'];
        $tentdate=$row['tentdate'];
        $progress=$row['progress'];
        $status=$row['status'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$cname."</td><td>".$podate."</td><td>".$started."</td><td>".$reason."</td><td>".$tentdate."</td><td>".$progress."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table><br>";
}
```

Everything works perfectly here and displays the table as required. But notice the variable `$td` above. I need that value displayed when my other button is clicked, which is in a different function.

Here's the code for the other button:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='fp' value='Finished payment'>";
if(isset($_GET['fp'])){
    echo $td;
}
```

Clicking that button doesn't display anything which means I am not able to read this variable outside the display function.I have tried looking up global variables in php and another solution was to use the  and then use Javascript but I want to use php and I need the text to remain in the text field after the submit button is clicked so that I can read it later.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the value in your hidden input field to display in the value of "fp" input field?

Comment: You can create a variable with that $_GET info and then post it in the value of the other input field.

Comment: i put the hidden field there as another way of trying the same thing. that didn't work either as i am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: See my answer it should help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a variable for the value, then place that variable in the value section of the other input.

```
$name= 'Enter Name';
if(isset($_GET['cname'])){
    $name = $_GET['cname'];
}
```

Then

```
<input type="text" name="cname" value="<?=$name?>">
```

Using placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="cname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>
```

Before the `$_GET['cname']` has been processed, the value within the input field is set to the text you wish to show, or simply keep it empty. Then once the `$_GET['cname']` has been posted, you check to see if it is set, then set the variable to equal the returned information the user entered in the other field - $td.

```
<?php
$cname = ''; // or $cname = 'Enter a Name';
if(isset($_GET['sub'])){
    display();
}
function display(){
    include 'config.php';
    $searchstr=$_GET['cname'];       
    $td=$_GET['cname'];

    $sql="select * from info where cname='$searchstr';";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($searchstr==""){
        $message="Please enter a customer name";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); 
        window.location.href='retreive.php';</script>";
    }
    else{
        //use isset to see if that has been posted
        if(isset($_GET['cname'])){            
           $name = $_GET['cname'];
           //$name is now set to the value you wish to display in the value of the other input
           //call on the value like so <input type="text" name="cname" value="<?=$name?>">
        }
        echo "<table id='info' border='1px solid black'><tr padding='2'><th>Customer Name</th><th>Purchase Order Date</th><th>Started?</th><th>Reason (If any)</th><th>Tentative start date</th><th>Progress</th><th>Current Status</th><th></tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cname=$row['cname'];
        $podate=$row['podate'];
        $started=$row['started'];
        $reason=$row['reason'];
        $tentdate=$row['tentdate'];
        $progress=$row['progress'];
        $status=$row['status'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$cname."</td><td>".$podate."</td><td>".$started."</td><td>".$reason."</td><td>".$tentdate."</td><td>".$progress."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";
       }
       echo "</table><br>";
    }
```

php fiddle: Good for 48 hours only - http://main.xfiddle.com/8f416cc9/input.php

Comment: okay my bad. I seemed to have missed something in the question. will edit it right now. basically, 'cname' already has a value and it is the value that i enter into the text field. my text field has the name 'cname' as i will edit in the question now. apologies for the incomplete question.

Comment: in the above edited code, i have the line `Enter customer name<input type="text" name="cname">` i want the text to remain in that input field after the first submit button is clicked. again, apologies for the inaccurate question.

Comment: `Enter customer name<input type="text" name="cname">`

Add the value section within the input tag and then set it to the variable coming from your post. 

`<input type="text" name="cname" value="<?=$cname">` in the value section you can invoke an if statement or declare a variable coming from an evaluation in your php file.  My example here shows a variable that was set to the posted variable. Just as my answer shows.

Comment: You can use the posted variable as well, just remember to make sure it is set first. `<input type="text" name="cname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cname'])){ echo $_POST['cname']; }esle{ echo 'Enter a name'; } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Once you submit the form, the text entered by the user disappeared? It's the default behavior of the browser. To avoid this either submit form using jQuery or store the value of the input into variable and echo.

Sample code for Jquery:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {

    //prevent Default functionality
    e.preventDefault();

    //get the action-url of the form
    var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;

    //do your own request an handle the results
    $.ajax({
            url: actionurl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                ... do something with the data...
            }
    });

});
```

==If not using Jquery==

PHP:

```
$myValue = $_POST['my_input_name'];
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="<?= $myValue ?>">
```